# PHP adjust time zone for date

Tags: php, date, timezone

The following output on my website is -1 hr, and I just wanted a quick fix to adjust it accordingly, but I'm not sure of the correct syntax...

```
<?php echo date('D, jS F @ g:ia', strtotime($row->datetime)); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I think this needs more info. What time zone is `$row->datetime` in and what does it contain?

Comment: What timezone is $row->datetime?

Comment: $row->datetime is no more than a DATETIME output from a mysql database ie. I set the column value to 27th July 2013 at 18:00... The above output is 27th July 2013 at 17:00 @Pekka웃

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function of PHP to set the your timezone as default it is taking the timezone of server.

Here is the [list of timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php).

Answer (score 2):

set default time zone

```
$timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
$stored_time = '2011-01-30 18:23:49';

date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$timestamp = strtotime($stored_time);
$local_time = $timestamp + date('Z');
$local_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $local_time);

echo $local_date;
```

Comment: you have missed some thing as you have not declare the `$user_timezone` variable anywhere.

Comment: This will return the wrong time, if the local timezone is already correctly set to the requested timezone. You will need to check if the local timezone isn't already set and thus not add or subtract the 'new' timezone