# Convert input hour from source timezone to UTC

Tags: php, datetime

I need to convert the input hours(12 hour format) from source timezone to UTC.

Like if I give 10 AM, Asia/Kolkata, I need converted it to 3:30 PM as per the offset in UTC.

Comment: use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) objects, and pay particular heed to the [setTimezone()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) method.... there's even examples if you read that page

Comment: Couldn't get to exact soln. I needed, all examples were converting the current timestamp or there were no example for 12-hour format

Comment: Look at the DateTime object constructor, or createFromFormat() to create a DateTime object: spoon-feeding time `$dt = new DateTime('10 AM', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')); $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC')); echo $dt->format('H:i:s);`

Comment: Couldn't be easier than that, @Mark Baker, and yes in this case I needed spoon feeding. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

use gmdate() function to get your desired result

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$the_date = strtotime("2010-01-19 00:00:00");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz",$the_date);
echo date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz", $the_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it works perfectly for me ..

```
$timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
echo $stored_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$timestamp = strtotime($stored_time);
$local_time = $timestamp + date('Z');
$local_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $local_time);
echo $local_date;
```

it is answered by me already for this question : [PHP adjust time zone for date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425587/php-adjust-time-zone-for-date/17425678#17425678)