# Get Current Time With given Timezone offset

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

I have time zone offset in my database field. and I need to compare (created_date + time zone offset)  with (current date + time zone offset).

```
DATE(created_date + INTERVAL timezone_offset SECOND)
```

i know how to add time zone in created date field. but i have to add time zone with `date("Y-m-d H:i:s)`.

I need the following in mysql query,

```
DATE("use php date function to get current date and time" + INTERVAL timezone_offset SECOND)
```

SQL Query Sample:

```
SELECT * FROM `admin` AS `A`
  INNER JOIN `timezones` AS `T` ON `T`.`admin_id`=`A`.`admin_id`
  WHERE (DATE(A.current_date + INTERVAL T.timezone_offset SECOND) != DATE('current    datetime by php function ' + INTERVAL T.timezone_offset SECOND)))
```

Please help.

Comment: check this reference this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425587/php-adjust-time-zone-for-date/17425678#17425678

Comment: @RajeevRanjan, i have checked that. how its possible to add it in mysql query?

Comment: DATE(created_date + INTERVAL timezone_offset SECOND) is similar to $local_date in that question just use it and pass your database offset to get date you desired...

Comment: i do not have to display date. i have to compare both date in mysql query.

Comment: please put your complete query ...

Comment: @RajeevRanjan, please check Sql Query Sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s)` function in you sql Query as following.

```
"SELECT * FROM `admin` AS `A`
   INNER JOIN `timezones` AS `T` ON `T`.`admin_id`=`A`.`admin_id`
    WHERE (DATE(A.current_date + INTERVAL T.timezone_offset SECOND) != DATE('".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' + INTERVAL T.timezone_offset SECOND)));"
```

You just have to add date("Y-m-d H:i:s") function in Sql Query.

Comment: Anything this complex is vulnerable to errors. I vastly prefer a simpler approach - and CONVERT_TZ is made to do this cleanly and simply.

Answer (score 2):

If your MySQL instance has the timezone tables loaded (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), then you can use the very convenient CONVERT_TZ function.

```
CONVERT_TZ(created_date, {time zone name that created_date is created in}, {time zone name you want})
```

I use it all the time and it is very handy.

Comment: Please use this.  Don't simply add seconds to a date... it doesn't take Daylight Savings Time into account and other timezone related weirdness.  CONVERT_TZ will.